# How to use new_record?, changed? and persisted? methods in rails in this example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to undestand [new record?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/582a90c09386839d7374fa1933ca4d805e1140a1/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L71),[changed ?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L102) and [persisted ?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/582a90c09386839d7374fa1933ca4d805e1140a1/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L84) on the example below.

How, this code has this result:

```
 # NOW
 # there is 0 new record after running new_data array
 # there is 0 changed record(s) after running new_data array
 # there is 3 persisted record(s) after running new_data array
```

Trying to come to this result:

```
# WANT
#there is 1 new record(s) after running new_data array
#there is 1 changed record(s) after running new_data array
#there is 2 persisted record(s) after running new_data array
```

**Question is: **

How to do it?. Want to record the number of changed and new records.

```
Cars.delete_all

original_data = [
    {:brand => 'Mercedes', :used => false, :year => 2000 },
    {:brand => 'Honda',    :used => true , :year => 2000 },
    {:brand => 'Nissan',   :used => false, :year => 2000 }
]

new_data = [
    # updating year to 2013
    {:brand => 'Mercedes', :used => false, :year => 2013 },
    # new record
    {:brand => 'Tesla', :used => false, :year => 2013  },
    # same data
    {:brand => 'Nissan', :used => false, :year => 2000 }
]


# create new cars
original_data.each do |c|
  Cars.create(c)
end

# updates
persisted =   0
new_records = 0
changed_records = 0
new_data.each do |c|
 car =  Cars.where(:brand => c[:brand]).first_or_create
 persisted   +=1 if car.persisted?
 new_records +=1 if car.new_record?
 changed_records +=1 if car.changed?
end

puts "there is #{new_records} new record(s) after running new_data array"
puts "there is #{changed_records} changed record(s) after running new_data array"
puts "there is #{persisted} persisted record(s) after running new_data array"
```

---

****UPDATE****

code according to answer:
- attempt to change only 1 record, not 2.

```
# updates
persisted =   0
new_records = 0
changed_records = 0
new_data.each do |c|
 car =  Cars.where(:brand => c[:brand]).first_or_initialize
 car.assign_attributes(c)
 persisted   +=1 if car.persisted?
 new_records +=1 if car.new_record?
 changed_records +=1 if car.changed?
 car.save
end

there is 1 new record(s) after running new_data array
there is 2 changed record(s) after running new_data array
there is 2 persisted record(s) after running new_data array
```

Comment: if you're expect to have 1 item created and 1 item updated, how come that you want 3 items to be persisted?

Comment: question is updated for persistance expectation as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that a new model which gets some new values assigned to its properties is considered changed. If so, the result would make sense, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [first_or_initialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) along with [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes)

```
new_data.each do |c|
 car =  Cars.where(:brand => c[:brand]).first_or_initialize
 new_records +=1 if car.new_record?
 car.save # first save the initialized AR
 car.assign_attributes(c)
 changed_records +=1 if car.changed?
 car.save
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I might not answer your question directly but I will try explain the Activerecord lifecyle methods.

**new_record?**

```
car = Car.new # => initialize a new Car object
car.new_record? # => true
```

**persisted?**

```
car.save
car.persisted? # => true
```

**changed?**

```
car.model = 'New release model S'
car.changed? # => true
```

**destroyed?**

```
car.destroy
car.destroyed? # => true
```

Comment: Car.new_record?, here we need to check for Car's instance, which is stored in car variable here. So, the correct way would be car.new_record?

Comment: You were right @NBSamar. Updated!

Comment: This answer is oversimplification when it comes to `persisted?` logic